# how to show video calls in firebug?

Tags: html, video, firebug

In Chrome, when you look in the Developer Tools, you can see the HTML5-video calls it is making. (I'm serving them chunked per MB, so every 10-12s there is 1 file downloaded).

But in Firefox (with Firebug), I can't see these calls?

How is that possible, and what can I do to show these?
This is the HTML page I'm showing:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/icons.css' />
<!--
    <link href="/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/ie8/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
<video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" poster="/thumbs/movie.jpg" data-setup="{}" preload="none">
  <source src="/movie.mp4?read=1" type='video/mp4'>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
<!--
    <script src="/video.min.js"></script>
-->
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome I can see this:

```
GET /movie.mp4?read=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: ******
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://*****/movie.mp4
Accept-Language: nl,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Range: bytes=4000000-
```

In Firebug... Nothing...

I tried already looking it up on Google, but or I am not using the right terms, or noone else had the same issue before.

I'm hoping that someone here can point out what I could do about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/). Did you already try the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) to see if the request is shown there?

Comment: @SebastianZartner: yes, actually I didn't know that Firebug was discontinued. But now I removed it and tried CTRL-SHIFT-I, and the look was exactly the same. So I'm guessing they merged. Anyway, that was the same interface as I was looking at. After removing Firebug (not just disabling) and restarting Firefox, I still can't see the calls being made.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: seems there is a subtle difference between those 2. The looks are the same, but when I press the play button, there is a difference. Well, now I can go to my next questions.
If you add this as an answer I can accept this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I thought this might be a bug in Firebug. And as [Firebug is officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/), the Firefox DevTools should be used instead. But I realized that the DevTools have the same problem, which gave me the idea that this must be an underlying issue.

So, the actual reason is that the video is cached once it's downloaded and reloading the page circumventing the cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or disabling the browser cache doesn't cause to it to be downloaded again.

You need to clear the cache (via the dialog available via Firefox menu > *History* > *Clear Recent History...* or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>). Then the video is downloaded again and shown in the network request lists in Firebug and the Firefox DevTools.

**Firebug:**
[image: Video request in Firebug]

**Firefox DevTools**
[image: Video request in Firefox DevTools]

There are several bugs filed for this. One of them, related to the Firefox DevTools, is [bug 1277514](https://bugzil.la/1277514).

Comment: Ok, hence the confusion! I tried CTRL-F5, but that didn't work. Even disabling the network cache in Firebug didn't work... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found three bug reports related to this issue, [bug 1277514](https://bugzil.la/1277514), [bug 1277798](https://bugzil.la/1277798), and [bug 1324883](https://bugzil.la/1324883) (which might be duplicates of each other).